# Working with Markers and Polylines Google Maps android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm doing an app in Android that works with google maps, in which a user establishes routes and another user can add markers to indicate traffic jam , something like waze.
The routes are polylines and the traffic jam are markers from a database.

My question: Is  there a function or something that I can use to know when a route (polyline) is above a marker in the map ?.
I hope I was clear, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the list of LatLng of the polyline and the position of your marker you can use [PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java#L164) from https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils